# mirror desktop behavior Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: display, display-resolution

Im wondering something about how Ubuntu chooses which desktop is to be mirrored. Is it the primary that is always mirrored onto the secondary?

What happens when the primary resolution isnt supported by the secondary? Does it switch to the closest shared resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mirror displays in Ubuntu, the OS behaves like you have one monitor.

If you had extended displays before, any files shown on the secondary monitor will be moved to the primary (and only) monitor.

If one monitor can't support the other's resolution, Ubuntu will set it to the highest possible common resolution. This can result in stretching or black bars, depending on your video card and monitors.